# Converting array of binary numbers to decimal

Tags: c

I am trying to convert an array of binary characters to Decimal. My code looks something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   int STRING_SIZE = 32;
   int stringLength = 0; 
   char input[STRING_SIZE];
   int arrayCounter = 0; 
   int base = 0;
   char decimalValue[stringLength];
   int exponent = 0;
   int remainder[stringLength];

printf("\nPlease enter a Binary, Decimal or Hexadecimal value no longer than 32 characters. ");
scanf("%s", input);
fgetc(stdin);

//Count the length of the string.
while (input[stringLength] != 0) { 
    printf("%c", input[stringLength]);
    stringLength++;
 }

for (arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter != stringLength; arrayCounter++) {
    remainder[arrayCounter] = input[arrayCounter] - '0' / 10;
    decimalValue[arrayCounter] = decimalValue[arrayCounter] + remainder[arrayCounter] * base;
    input[arrayCounter] = input[arrayCounter] / 10;
    base = base * 2;
    printf("%c", decimalValue[arrayCounter]);
 }

printf("%s", decimalValue);



return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I know how to convert between binary and Decimal, but I am extremely confused on how to convert binary to decimal when the input is an array of characters.

Comment: So do I understand it correctly, that you are trying to convert a c_string (char[]) representing a binary number into a new string representing a decimal number?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert the string into a new string representing the decimal value. E.g input: 10 (binary), output: 2 (decimal)

Comment: Is there some specific reason you want to implement this yourself? Otherwise, I recommend using strol()  with base 2 [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/] to turn the string to an integer, and then sprintf to turn the integer back to a string.

Comment: Part of an assignment, our teacher wants us to implement it ourselves.

Comment: You never convert `input[arrayCounter]` from ASCII to decimal, e.g. `input[arrayCounter] -= '0'`, you do for `remainder`, but not for the stored character. (you should use another variable also rather than changing the character value -- but that's up to you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was similar question asked(Binary to Decimal and Hex (bit by bit)
) where I had replied to use formula below to convert binary chars to decimal

2^7 * (1 OR 0) + 2^6 * (1 OR 0) + 2^5 * (1 OR 0) + 2^4 * (1 OR 0) + 2^3 * (1 OR 0) + 2^2 * (1 OR 0) + 2^1 * (1 OR 0) + 2^0 * (1 OR 0)

Below is the sample code you can refer that does it, you can take `bstr` in input instead of initializing at declaration

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char bstr[]="10011";
int i=0;
int len  = strlen(bstr);
int sum = 0;
int j = 0;

for(i=(len-1);i>=0;i--)
{
    sum = sum + (pow(2,i) * (bstr[j] - '0'));
    j++;
}
printf("decimal = %d\n",sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this, but I am receiving a different output.

    `for (i= stringLength- 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        decimalValue = decimalValue + (power(2, i)) * (input[arrayCounter] - '0');
        arrayCounter++;
    }
    
    printf("\n%d", decimalValue);`



INPUT: 10 
Output: 112

Comment: Are you sure decimalValue is initialized to 0

Comment: Just checked, I had it initialized as a Char, changed it to Int and it is initialized to 0. Output now returns -144 when input 10.

Comment: arrayCounter is it initialized to zero? you would have to debug to see whats going wrong

Comment: Of course that was the problem! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Note:  you can use `sum = sum + (1u << i) * (bstr[j] - '0');` to eliminate your dependency on `math.h` for computing a simple power of 2. I would also recommend using `unsigned` or `uint32_t` (from `stdint.h`) for your types as computing the result of negative input (full 32-bit values in twos-compliment format) would take a bit of additional work.  (other nit, is `strlen` returns `size_t`) and for short words you can eliminate `string.h` by initializing `size_t len = 0;` then `for (; bstr[len]; len++) {}`. Those are just optional tweaks for a further look at indexing `:)`

Comment: For style points you can just loop `while (len--) sum += (1u << i) * (bstr[j++] - '0');` as your complete loop construct `:)`